# Различное количество доменов при выходе с сайта

Tags: поддержка

Кода я выхожу с сайта stackoverflow у меня появляется список каких-то семи сайтов и требуется подтверждение "выйти на всех устройствах". Вот список сайтов:

- askubuntu.com
- mathoverflow.net
- serverfault.com
- stackapps.com
- stackexchange.com
- stackoverflow.com
- superuser.com

Но иногда в этом списке не семь сайтов, а только один - stackoverflow.com.

Вопросы:

1. Что за семь сайтов, на которые я не входил, но которые требуют, чтобы я вышел?
2. На каких таких "всех устройствах" я должен выйти? Если я сижу за своим одним компом и знать не знаю никаких других устройств.
3. Почему иногда вместо списка из семи сайтов появляется список только из одного сайта?

---

Привожу скриншот:

> [image: только SO]

Для сравнения привожу скриншот, когда появляется список из семи сайтов:

> [image: несколько сайтов]

Comment: По вопросу. Все сообщества в списке оформлены в виде ссылок. Вы можете убедиться, что залогинены там просто перейдя по этим ссылкам.

Comment: [Все сообщества в списке оформлены в виде ссылок] А почему иногда вместо семи сайтов в списке только один сайт? И почему этот список доступен только при выходе? И что значит "выйти на всех устройствах" если у меня всего одно устройство?

Comment: Один сайт в списке значит, что вы с этим токеном заходили только на один сайт..

Comment: Подобная логика есть во всех продуктах google - gmail и тп

Comment: @vp_arth Я всегда захожу на сайт одинаково. А при выходе вижу разные картинки. И на другие сайты из списка я не хожу.

Comment: Если Вы действительно не ходите на другие сайты из списка - вероятно, это [meta-tag:дефект]

Comment: @pepsicoca1 чем детальнее вы протестируете и точнее сформулируете условия дефекта, тем больше это поможет его исправить

Comment: Пожалуйста, не плодите топики. Если хотите добавить скриншот - отредактируйте существующий вопрос

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov Зря Вы закрыли тот вопрос, я стер свои экземпляры скриншотов и теперь Вы не сможете поправить ошибку на вашем сайте.

Comment: @pepsicoca1 ну, раз такое дело, перенес сюда ваши "потерянные" скриншоты сам

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov Не надо делать мне одолжения. Ваше поведение выходит за все рамки приличия.

Answer (score 4):

По пункту 2. "Выйти на всех устройствах" - это фраза которая уже давно стала стандартной и ее много где можно увидеть (правда, обычно ее прячут в настройках безопасности аккаунта, а не показывают на странице выхода). Слово "всех" тут употребляется в математическом смысле, то есть если вы используете всего одно устройство, то оно и есть "все". Кстати, разные браузеры считаются за разные устройства.

Эта галочка нужна на тот случай, когда вы, к примеру, зашли на SO с чужого компьютера в гостях или, к примеру, из интернет-кафе, а потом ушли забыв выйти. Или же ее можно использовать если вы зашли на SO с телефона, а потом этот телефон потеряли (собственно, после широкого распространения смартфонов такая формулировка и устоялась).

Comment: Вообще-то обычно такая галочка называется "чужой компьютер" и предлагается при входе а не при выходе. Ну да ладно, на SO все сделано как-то мягко говоря нетривиально. Но почему иногда у меня вместо семи сайтов в списке только один? Я могу запостить скриншот, правда сейчас у меня нет скриншота, но если надо то сделаю. Примерно 1 раз в 10-20 посещений сайта вместо списка из семи сайтов появляется список из одного сайта. У вас что, дружное сообщество сайтов иногда разваливается? :-)

Comment: @pepsicoca1 галочка "чужой компьютер" делает немного другое - говорит использовать для аутентификации сессионную куку вместо персистентной. Тоже полезная вещь - но ее проблема в том что ставить ее надо заранее.

Comment: На другие ваши вопросы я ответа не знаю, можно не повторять их в комментариях.

Comment: Ну вот к примеру зашел я на чужом компе на SO и ушел забыв выйти. Как при этом мне поможет галочка "выйти на всех устройствах"?

Comment: @pepsicoca1 вы вспоминаете об этом, заходите на SO на своем компе, а потом выходите обратно с галочкой

Comment: То есть я зашел зашел я на чужом компе скажем в интернет-кафе на SO и ушел забыв выйти. После этого я еду домой два часа, захожу на SO со своего компа, ставлю  "выйти на всех устройствах" и в далеком интернет-кафе закрывается сессия? Не, ну это конечно полезная фича, но Вы не находите что реакция выглядит как-то запоздало? :-)

Comment: @pepsicoca1 лучше так чем никогда

Comment: Да уж, логика более чем нетривиальная. :-) Почему же на других форумах я никогда такого не видел? Как-то обходятся люди, при выходе закрывают все сессии на всех устройствах без всяких галочек и не парятся. :-)

Comment: @pepsicoca1 никогда никто при выходе не закрывает все сессии, обычно только текущую закрывают. А сброс всех открытых сессий обычно привязывают к смене пароля. Но на этом сайте не у всех пользователей пароль есть.