# Где и кому можно пожаловаться на действия модераторов на сайте SO?

Tags: обсуждение, дефект, поддержка, модерация, модераторский-произвол

На сайте SO существует один персонаж. Несмотря на свой статус модератора он занимается флудом и спамом. Где и кому я могу пожаловаться на действия этого модератора?

UPD1:

Есть два обсуждения. Одно на:

[Как исполняется машинный код и как система ограничивает его права?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/853040/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0/853267#853267)

В этом первом обсуждении участник стирает мои ответы на его вопросы в комментариях. Более странного поведения трудно себе представить.

Второе обсуждение на двух вопросах:

[Выход с сайта stackoverflow](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7604/%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%81-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0-stackoverflow)

[Выход с сайта stackoverflow (продолжение) [дубликат]](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7625/%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%81-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0-stackoverflow-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

Во втором обсуждении участник почему-то требует отформатировать мои вопросы в соответствии с его представлениями о прекрасном.

UPD2:

Только что участник (имя которого нельзя называть) стер обсуждение

[Выход с сайта stackoverflow (продолжение) [дубликат]](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7625/%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%81-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0-stackoverflow-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

Все бы ничего, но у меня нет дубликатов приведенных там скриншотов. Поэтому теперь сайт SO останется без документов о странном поведении сайта при выходе. Кроме того, в обсуждении ко второму вопросу были комментарии, в которых другие участники подтверждали что тоже видели такое поведение сайта.

UPD3: удалено модераторами без объяснения причин

UPD4:

Ну так что же? Не вижу ответа администрации сайта с извинениями за поведение этого участника. Не вижу восстановления удаленных им моих комментариев. Не вижу восстановления удаленного им моего вопроса. Или администрация считает, что все нормально?

Comment: [Список модераторов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators)

Comment: Он не модератор, а обычный участник. Пожаловаться лично можно через форму поддержки: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/contact

Comment: Убрал имя. Пожалуйста, не обсуждайте **людей**, лучше обсуждайте **поведение**. Расскажите подробнее, в чём проблема.

Comment: @Nick Volynkin Он редактирует мои вопросы и стирает мои ответы на его комментарии. Из этого я делаю вывод, что у него есть права модератора. А где находится форма поддержки, через которую можно пожаловаться?

Comment: @Nick Volynkin Не очень понимаю, как можно обсуждать поведение без имени. Ну да ладно. Есть два обсуждения. Одно на  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/853040/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0/853267#853267

Comment: Вероятно, вам стоит написать ответ в [Тему об удалении комментариев](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7095/176064) с примерами удалённых Ваших комментариев. Вероятно, с вашей помощью система будет улучшена.

Comment: В этом первом обсуждении Pavel Mayorov стирает мои ответы на его вопросы в комментариях. Более странного поведения трудно себе представить.

Comment: @Nick Volynkin Второе обсуждение на https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7604/%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%81-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0-stackoverflow

Comment: Во втором обсуждении Pavel Mayorov почему-то требует отформатировать мои вопросы в соответствии с его представлениями о прекрасном.

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите пример! И поместите в тело вопроса пояснения о проблеме, чтобы для полного понимания не нужно было читать комментарии.

Comment: Дубликат? https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7226/10105

Comment: @VladD, в данном случае участник не имеет отношения к администрации

Comment: @Grundy: Я руководствуюсь текстом вопроса, в котором есть слово «модератор». Если вопрос будет отредактирован, тогда да, но покамест нет.

Comment: @VladD, модераторы не имеют отношения к администрации

Comment: @vp_arth: В вопросе, который я предлагаю как дубликат, под словом «администрация» понимается комплект из модераторов и работников компании.

Comment: @pepsicoca1 Пожалуйста, спокойней и дружелюбней относитесь к другим участникам. Также вам будет намного легче помогать изучить особенности работы данного сайта или усваивать информацию от вас о 
потенциальных дефектах данного сайта, если вы будете общаться в более доброжелательном и дружелюбном тоне.

Comment: @VladD а в этом вопросе, очевидно, под "модераторами" подразумеваются еще и участники с репутацией более 2к :-)

Comment: @Vadim Ovchinnikov Пожалуйста, оставьте свои советы при себе. Как только что мне было разъяснено, "комментарии к ответам предназначены для уточнения технических аспектов ответов. а не для указания другим участникам, что им делать". Не верите - поглядите чуть ниже в обсуждении к ответу.

Comment: @pepsicoca1 Это относится к основному сайту, а не к мете. Вашу обратную связь проще будет воспринимать, если вы перестаните доносить мысли в таком тоне.

Comment: @Vadim Ovchinnikov ах, на мете у вас другие правила? То есть на мете я могу посоветовать Вам, что Вам Vadim Ovchinnikov надо делать? Ну что же, могу посоветовать Вам на мете перестать давать мне советы, потому что я не нуждаюсь в Ваших советах ни по какому вопросу.

Answer (score 4):

> В этом первом обсуждении участник стирает мои ответы на его вопросы в комментариях. Более странного поведения трудно себе представить.

Ваши комментарии были удалены системой по флагу от участника, т.к. попали под [маску автоматического удаления](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7095/). Возможно, это было ложное срабатывание. Маску, скорее всего, пересмотрят в ближайшем будущем.

> Второе обсуждение на двух вопросах:

Это один вопрос. Не стоит задавать один вопрос снова и снова. Если вы хотите добавить какую-то информацию о проблеме - **отредактируйте существующий пост**, а не создавайте новый. Это часть правил сайта, а не "представления о прекрасном" какого-то одного участника.

> удалено модераторами без объяснения причин

Удалил я (и это видно из истории ревизий вопроса). Пожалуйста, [соблюдайте принятые на сайте нормы поведения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/conduct) и не переходите на личности.

> Ну так что же? Не вижу ответа администрации сайта с извинениями за поведение этого участника. Не вижу восстановления удаленных им моих комментариев. Не вижу восстановления удаленного им моего вопроса. Или администрация считает, что все нормально?

Этот участник - не модератор, не представитель администрации, и он действовал в рамках правил. Достаточно странно ожидать за это извинений от администрации :)

Comment: Интересно, простой участник удаляет мой комментарий по каким-то там причинам. Я, такой же простой участник, считаю, что комментарий не надо удалять. Кто же прав в этой ситуации?

Comment: @pepsicoca1 ваш комментарий стоило бы отдать на обработку живым модераторам. стоит пересмотреть маску. т.е. это техническая проблема, а не "злой участник взял и все снес"

Comment: Ну так восстановите снесенный комментарий. В чем проблема-то?

Comment: @pepsicoca1 проблема в том, что движок по какой-то странной причине не позволяет восстанавливать некоторые комментарии. по поводу этого конкретного комментария - если его восстановят, я, как модератор, сразу удалю его - комментарии к ответам предназначены для уточнения технических аспектов ответов. а не для указания другим участникам, что им делать.

Comment: Злой Паша такой Злой... Если система автоудалятора плоха (о чём мы говорили ещё давно), то почему чистильщики не позаботились о исправлении или отключении адской машины?

Comment: @Other озаботились - https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7675/177221, жду пока плюсов набежит, а то непонятно, вдруг кто-то против отключения

Comment: @PashaPash, Отлично, спасибо (и тут этот коммент улетает автоудалятором :))!