# Куда жаловаться, если не согласен с действиями модератора?

Tags: поддержка, модерация, правки

Только что один из модераторов поправил [мой ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1051706/178988) (версия 13) в соответствии с его понятиями о прекрасном.  Удалены некоторые предложения и переформатирован ответ. Мотив - "Удалены неотносящиеся к ответу фразы". А я считаю, что все фразы в ответе вполне относятся к ответу. Доколе будет продолжаться беспредел и есть ли управа на модераторов на этом благословенном сайте?

UPD1:

> На ответе стояла тревога "Невежливый или оскорбительный".

Ну и что? Кому-то показалось что-то оскорбительным? А мне показалось, что баба Маня из соседнего подъезда слишком много пьёт и что теперь? Никакой нецензурной лексики в ответе не было, а все ваши фантазии можете оставить у себя в мониторе. Термин "дикие Unix-оиды" вполне литературное выражение, можете поинтересоваться милицейским справочником нецензурной лексики, так вот в нём термина "дикие Unix-оиды" нет. Следовательно, всё вполне цензурно.

> Информация о том, кто по твоему мнению минусует сообщение, ответом
>   никак являться не может.
>   В комментариях ещё ладно, но точно не в ответе.

Почему мне нельзя в ответе прокомментировать необъяснимую волну минусов?

> Маркеры UPD 1 ... UPD N, очевидно, полезной информации не приносят.
>   Это ответ, а не чат.

Маркеры UPD 1 ... UPD N играют важную роль, они показывают развитие диалога.

> Я перенёс некоторые куски, которые мне было жалко удалять вместе с
>   жалобами на минусаторов, и постарался придать им связный вид.

Вас никто не просил ничего редактировать. Если Вы имеете что-то сказать по делу, напишите свой ответ. Обещаю, что я не буду его править.

> Это ответ и его вполне можно править дальше, если что-то из
>   исправлений не устраивает.

Вот ещё не хватало мне устраивать гонки по вертикали со всякими доброхотами. Просто отстаньте от чужих ответов, это не Ваше дело - править чужие ответы.

И да, зачем Вы удалили смайлы? Смайлы что, тоже под запретом на stackoverflow?

UPD2:

Почему из вопроса и из заголовка стерли ник модератора Qwertiy♦? Это что, запрещенное слово?

UPD3:

> Даже если в сообщении нет нецензурщины, оное всё равно может быть
>   обидным.

Знаете, экстрасенсы все в отпуске. Не могу же я знать, что будет обидным для каждого из семи миллиардов пользователей интернета? Давайте уж как-то выруливать хотя бы к юридическим формулировкам оскорбления.

UPD4:

> На мете обсуждают ситуацию, а не конкретных людей.

Вот такая ситуация - конкретный человек превышает свои полномочия и редактирует чужие ответы. Почему бы при этом не упомянуть его ник?

UPD5:

> Я не вижу, где бы я удалял смайлы.

Вы даже не контролируете свои руки. Смайл удален после слов "всей системы команд PDP-11."

UPD6:

> Ответ - это не диалог. Для диалогов есть чат. В крайнем случае
>   комментарии. Ответы же нужны для ответов на вопросы.

Участники задают дополнительные вопросы в комментариях. Ответы на эти дополнительные вопросы слишком велики, чтобы быть помещенными в комментариях. Поэтому приходится дополнять ответ. Чтобы все не смешивалось в кучу, (чтобы не смешивалось в кучу и основной ответ и ответы на дополнительные вопросы) и служат маркеры UPD.

UPD7:

> Неправда, смайл на месте:

А в истории правок этот смайл зачеркнут. Движок барахлит?

UPD8:

> Добавления нового фрагмента в вопрос вполне достаточно, помечать его
>   номером не требуется.

Не требуется, но и не запрещается. Мне кажется, что если помечать новый фрагмент номером, то становится понятнее где кончается один ответ и где начинается следующий ответ. Если Вам так не кажется, Вы можете в своих ответах все валить в кучу. А мне уж позвольте форматировать мои ответы так, как мне кажется правильным.

UPD9:

> так что логично её удалить заодно.

Логично просто никогда не лезть в чужие ответы. Повторю еще раз - если Вам что-то не нравится, Вы всегда можете написать свой ответ в котором сказать что линуксоиды вовсе не дикие, что Вы много раз кормили линуксоидов с рук и все пальцы у вас целы. Что Cmake это мейнстрим и все программисты в мире поголовно сейчас радостно пишут руками конфиги для Cmake. А также можете объяснить ТС ЗАЧЕМ ему бросать комфортное IDE и в 2019 году от Рождества Христова начинать руками писать конфиги для Cmake. В своем ответе Вы также можете никогда не употреблять маркеры UPD, отказаться от смайлов ну и вообще проделать все, что Вы хотите.

UPD10:

> Может, вместо того чтобы править поток сознания, лучше такие ответы
>   просто удалять?

Может Вы,  Pavel Mayorov, покажете где у вас индульгенция определять у кого поток сознания а у кого нет?

Comment: Связанное обсуждение: [Где и кому можно пожаловаться на действия модераторов на сайте SO?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7662/15479).

Comment: Ещё частично [здесь](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7226/15479).

Comment: Оскорбления - это не только нецензурная лексика. Даже если в сообщении нет нецензурщины, оное всё равно может быть обидным.

Comment: Ник стёрли, т.к: 1) На мете обсуждают ситуацию, а не конкретных людей. 2) Совершенно не важно, кто из модераторов это сделал. Это мог быть я.

Comment: Ну-ну, посмотри внимательнее...

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9803/178988

Comment: Может, вместо того чтобы править поток сознания, лучше такие ответы просто удалять?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Связанные обсуждения:

   - [Где и кому можно пожаловаться на действия модераторов на сайте SO?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7662/15479).
   - [Какие предусмотрены пути опротестования решения администрации?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7226/15479).
2. Сообщить о каких-то проблема с модерацией можно через [контактную форму](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/contact).
3. Почему вы акцентируете внимание на том, что участник является модератором? [Править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) сообщения может любой участник с 2,000 репутации. Следовательно, как мне кажется, решать надо с позиции не согласия с правкой участника. Статус модератора здесь не является ключевым в обсуждении.
4. Фразы про "обиды" и "диких" - это, в общем-то, оскорбления. Это даже если не брать в расчёт, что подобное вообще к ответу отношения никакого не имеет.
5. > Коллеги, не забывайте, что вы минусите ПОДТВЕРЖДЕННЫЙ ответ.

   Подтверждённый ответ лишь говорит о принятии автором вопроса. Это не значит, что сообщество должно такой ответ принимать/поддерживать. В общем-то, вам в комментариях даже указали на проблемы вашего ответа.

Answer (score 9):

1. На ответе стояла тревога "Невежливый или оскорбительный".
2. Информация о том, кто по твоему мнению минусует сообщение, ответом никак являться не может. В комментариях ещё ладно, но точно не в ответе.
3. Маркеры `UPD 1` ... `UPD N`, очевидно, полезной информации не приносят. Это ответ, а не чат.
4. Я перенёс некоторые куски, которые мне было жалко удалять вместе с жалобами на минусаторов, и постарался придать им связный вид.
5. В остальном я стилистику не менял, только поудалял лишнее.
6. Это ответ и его вполне можно править дальше, если что-то из исправлений не устраивает.
7. Информация о том, что ответ принят, не означает того, что он правильный. Автор вопроса всего лишь один человек, который таким образом выражает своё мнение. К тому же, он в любой момент может передумать и переставить галочку на любой другой ответ.
8. А ещё, в данном вопросе очевидно, что автор совершенно не является экспертом в данной теме, поэтому выставлять его мнение как единственно верное, вообще странно.

> Ну и что? Кому-то показалось что-то оскорбительным?

Я удалил то, что не относилось к вопросу. Я даже в комментарии не писал про удаление оскорблений. Но вообще-то и формулировки вполне можно было почистить.

> Почему мне нельзя в ответе прокомментировать необъяснимую волну минусов?

Потому что ответ - это ответ на заданный вопрос. В вопросе нет ничего про минусы, вопрос только про cmake. И даже в этом предложении ты используешь слово *"прокомментировать"* - это надо делать в комментариях, а не в ответах.

> Маркеры UPD 1 ... UPD N играют важную роль, они показывают развитие диалога.

Ответ - это не диалог. Для диалогов есть чат. В крайнем случае комментарии. Ответы же нужны для ответов на вопросы.

> И да, зачем Вы удалили смайлы? Смайлы что, тоже под запретом на stackoverflow?

Я не вижу, где бы я удалял смайлы. Единственное предложение со смайлом, которое я трогал, не удалено, а перенесено в конец. И во всём абзаце только незначительные правки орфографии. Просто сайт почему-то сравнивает не с тем абзацем и получается как будто изменилось всё. Я уже об этом [вопрос сам задал](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9803/178988). Впрочем, сомневаюсь, что кто-то будет это править, по крайней мере в ближайшее время.

[image: скриншот]

> Участники задают дополнительные вопросы в комментариях.

Тогда их вопрос можно процитировать в ответе и ответить на него. Добавления нового фрагмента в вопрос вполне достаточно, помечать его номером не требуется. А при удалении кусков ответа, некоторые из которых являются целыми апдеййтами, вообще какая-то фигня получится с нумерацией, так что логично её удалить заодно.

К тому же, вопрос "Почему и кто минусует ответ?" не является дополнительным к вопросом в обсуждении cmake. И его даже никто не задавал.

> Почему из вопроса и из заголовка стерли ник модератора Qwertiy♦?

А это не я. Я только ссылку на обсуждаемый ответ добавил и номер ревизии в нём.

Comment: "его вполне можно править дальше" Только войн правок не устраивайте (:

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica, ну, я в первую очередь имел в виду часть, где я собрал в кучку предложения из разных удалённых абзацев. Остальную стилистику я вроде не менял, только поудалял куски.

Comment: @ Suvitruf says Reinstate Monica вот это поворот в пятницу вечером :))