# Как-то криво работает diff

Tags: дефект

Вот фрагмент [diff'а](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1051706/revisions)

> [image: скриншот]

Показывается как будто первый абзац удалён, а второй полностью переписан. Хотя на самом деле убран как раз второй абзац, а в первом немного исправлено правописание.

Почему такое плохое сравнение? Надо бы улучшить.