# Довольны ли вы нашей модерацией?

Tags: обсуждение, модерация

Порой некоторые участники ругают нашу модерацию. Поэтому я решил устроить голосование:

> Довольны ли вы нашей модерацией?
>
> ---
>
> Считаете ли вы, что наши модераторы объективны и справедливы, или же есть претензии?

Если будут ссылки, подтверждающие ту или иную позицию, добавьте их правкой в соответствующий ответ.

*P.S.* Не надо закрывать этот вопрос, пока идет голосование. Я попрошу модераторов его заблокировать, когда оно закончится.

Comment: Кому модераторы идут навстречу, выполняя их просьбы — те довольны, кому не идут — недовольны ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @andreymal Ага, но не надо все-т'ки крыть матом в таком случае!

Comment: Так же как в постах @Denis640Kb здесь не хватает конкретики. В работе модераторов есть и успехи и проблемы. Мне думается что их нужно обсуждать по отдельности и в деталях. Бинарный ответ не очень полезен.

Comment: Немножко добавлю. В модерации могут быть проблемы, но обсуждать лучше более конкретно. Скажем, если участникам не нравится, что модераторы удаляют комментарии, то можно создать вопрос для обсуждения. Может модераторы действительно зря удаляют их, а может участники не знают правила? Кто знает)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В таком виде опрос бесполезен. Он только рассорит людей.

Также хочу напомнить ещё раз:

- [Следует ли обращаться к участникам по имени в вопросах на Мете?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4790/15479) Упоминание участника, который недоволен действиями модератора, не нужно. Важны факты. Если из вопроса убрать конкретные имена, смысл не изменится. Но зато уменьшится вероятность негатива по отношению к этим участникам.
- Не совсем понимаю, что будет по итогу этого вопроса. Если у участника проблемы, то ему этот опрос не поможет. У нас [есть процедуры, если участник недоволен действиями модератора](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9800/15479). Он всегда может [связаться](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/contact) с [управляющим](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/6/nicolas-chabanovsky?tab=profile) (у которого в профиле указаны и прямые контакты для связи, если у вас очень важный вопрос).

---

Небольшое уточнение по поводу обсуждений модерации на Мете. Это не запрещено, если вопрос удовлетворяет формальным требованиям:

- Никаких имён.
- Никаких нападок на других участников.
- **Пруфы/ссылки/факты**.

[Этот вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10327/15479) требованиям не удовлетворял, поэтому и был закрыт участниками. Но это не значит, что не нужно обсуждать проблемы сообщества. Нужно. Но давайте сдерживать эмоции и обсуждать всё как профессионалы.

Comment: @Sevastopol' и какой же у меня личный интерес в том вопросе? Чем он мне "удобен"?

Comment: @Sevastopol' и мне было грустно видеть, что участники беспочвенно начали друг друга обвинять и навязывать свою точку зрения. Удаление таких вопросов ни к чему хорошему не приведёт. Как раз наоборот, такие вопросы/обсуждения показывают, что есть какие-то трения/разногласия между людьми. И нужно эти проблемы решать, а не закапывать голову в песок.